# What are the limitations of non-negative matrix factorisation when reducing the dimensions of a data set?

Tags: r, machine-learning, data-visualization, dataset, non-negative-matrix-factorization

From what I understand NFM (non-negative matrix factorisation) is constrained by the factor that it only supports data sets with non-negative values when reducing the dimensions of a data set. Specifically, are there any only limitations that NFM has when carrying this out? in comparison to say PCA (Principle Component Analysis).

Comment: Non-negative matrix factorization is not restricted to positive values; it is restricted to *non-negative* values.